# I want to search nth line from one file in my workspace and replace it with nth line kept in another file

Tags: regex, linux, automation, macros, autohotkey

I am using notepad++ and file1.txt contains these lines

```
s:label key="getText('abc.ghi')"
s:label key="getText('bcd.dsf')"
s:label key="getText('sdfsf.fdg')"
s:label key="getText('ewrwer.hgfgh')"
```

I want to find 1st line 
 
 
i.e `s:label key="getText('abc.ghi')"`

 in my eclipse workspace(a directory containing list of different type of files ) and suppose it is present in file2.txt then make the replace there itself with 1st line from another file automatically (file3.txt) , similarly for all other lines.
 file3.txt contains

```
s:label key="getText('abc.ghi')" requiredLabel="true"
s:label key="getText('bcd.dsf')" requiredLabel="true"
s:label key="getText('sdfsf.fdg')" requiredLabel="true"
s:label key="getText('ewrwer.hgfgh')" requiredLabel="true"
```

is it possible to do it with macro?(I had trouble with notepad++ macro)

If the above is difficult I want to automatically search all lines in my workspace line by line from file1.txt and append it with `requiredLabel="true"` i.e 
For the 1st line, Search for the below line in workspace  
`s:label key="getText('abc.ghi')"` 
 
and replace it with 
 
`s:label key="getText('abc.ghi')" requiredLabel="true"` 
wherever it is present in my workspace
 
 
 similary for other lines

Answer (score 0):

I have NO idea what you want. Please get someone to translate your text into English.

"I want to find 1st line [...] in my eclipse workspace"
Is your eclipse workspace a file?? I don't get it.

Here is how to read line one from file1 and replace the first line of file2 with the first line of file1 followed by the text `requiredLabel="true"`:

```
file1 = C:\aaa\file1.txt
file2 = C:\aaa\file2.txt

FileReadLine, firstLineOfFile1, %file1%, 1
FileRead, file2Content, %file2%

replacementLine = %firstLineOfFile1%`nrequiredLabel="true"`n

newFile2Content := RegExReplace(file2Content,"^.+\R",replacementLine)
FileDelete, %file2%
FileAppend, %newFile2Content%, %file2%

MsgBox, %newFile2Content%
```

Comment: My eclipse workspace is collection of different type of files(.txt,.jsp,.java etc) I have edited my question and supported it with example . let know if any clarification required.